# Ubuntu 14.04 on MacBookPro 11,3 rEFInd boot issues

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, mac, refind

Last night in installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my MacBookPro 11,3 (Mid-2014 rMBP) and I used rEFInd as the bootloader, it worked, I installed wifi drivers, fixed my touchpad (I believe), and so on. Now, it doesn't want to boot at all, when I boot normally into Ubuntu I get a black screen with a blinking cursor, and upon entering the recovery mode I have some sort of SMP issue, which I hear the Haswell MBs have an issue with, and it does not boot. And sometimes when booting normally it stops at "Fast TSC Calibration Failed." The issues I'm having seem to be CPU related, but I don't know how to solve them.

P.S. This is my first Mac computer, any other computer I've ran Ubuntu on worked fine.

Thanks.

Comment: nosmp seems to make it boot, but is that a permanent solution?